# How do I proceed from here on finding the Binet's formula via generating functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

So, I'm stuck with the algebra for the nth number on the Fibonacci sequence in here.

I managed to get to the part where $G(x) = \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$ $=$ $\frac{x}{(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)}$, and I know that this can be written in the form of $\frac{A}{1-\alpha x} + \frac{B}{1-\beta x}$ which is going to get me to $\frac{\alpha^n - \beta^n}{\sqrt{5}}$, where $\alpha = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\beta = \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.

I just don't know how I can algebraically manipulate $\frac{x}{(1-\alpha x)(1-\beta x)}$ to $\frac{A}{1-\alpha x} + \frac{B}{1-\beta x}$.

Hopefully it's not something very obvious.

Sorry if bad english and if I assumed some wrong relation.

Comment: Have you heard of [partial fraction decomposition](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/partfrac.htm)?

Comment: You might be interested in the free book called generatingfunctionology by Wilf, where he goes over this very problem in the introductory chapters: http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html

Comment: Not until today, @JimmyK4542. Many thanks.

Comment: Will download it. Thank you @user14982305.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do know how to manipulate $\frac{x}{(1-\varphi x)(1-\Phi x)}=\frac{A}{1-\varphi x}+\frac{B}{1-\Phi x}$, because all of the manipulations required are from elementary algebra: clear denominators and expand using the distributive property. Then you just have to equate coefficients (constant and linear terms).

This procedure generalizes in a big way; search for *partial fraction decomposition*.